# Pass information from angular material button to controller

Tags: angularjs, button, angular-material

I am using angularjs v1 and angular material.

I am using this link as reference for adding angular material button.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

I have this simple angular material button. Here is the html code;

```
<md-button class="md-raised">Add Data</md-button>
```

When this button is pressed, I would like to run `console.log('button pressed');` inside my angular controller.

```
.controller('DataAddCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

    }])
```

Comment: Yes! :) THank you. I have selected it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="myFunc()">Add Data</md-button>
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('DataAddCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.myFunc = function() {
         console.log('button pressed');
      }
    }])
```

Learn more about `ng-click` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click=btnClick()>Add Data</md-button>



 .controller('DataAddCtrl', ['$scope', 
        function ($scope) {
    $scope.btnClick=function()
    {
       console.log('button pressed');
    }
    }])
```